# Java EE - No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver

Tags: java, sql-server, jakarta-ee, jdbc, intellij-idea

So I tried to connect to SQL Server in Java EE Intellij IDEA the thing is that I had a successful experience of connecting to my DB while ago in Java SE. I did everything that I did in there but I get error.
Here's screenshots.

Files:

[image: Files]

And here's database connection method:

[image: DB connection method]

And here's an error that I get:

[image: Error]

So how can I solve this? Thanks!
P.S. Yes, I have added driver as library.

Comment: The jar file `sqljdbc42.jar` must be in `WEB-INF/lib`, not in `WEB-INF`.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the driver in WEB-INF/lib instead. If you're using a EE server you should register it via JNDI

Comment: But there's no WEB-INF/lib. What's JNDI?

Comment: Java Naming And Directory. The server,  GlassFish will provide you with a datasource.

Comment: Create a folder named lib under WEB-INF and put the driver there. Standard location for libs in war file

Comment: Try to create an implemtation of `ServletContextListener` and override the `contextInitialized`. Here you call `DriverManager.registerDriver(<your jdbc driver>);`

Comment: Do you want to use EE features? Like `@PersistanceUnit` from the Java EE API or do want to manage the datasource in your webapp? If have no need for EE features, go for Jetty, Undertow or Tomcat